How to Globally Handle Enum Binding Errors in .NET Configuration
In my .NET Core application, I'm trying to handle configuration binding errors for enums without using TypeConverters or converting enums to strings.
I have a class in my app that looks something like this:
class Options
{
    public CategoryEnum Category { get; set; }
}

enum CategoryEnum
{
    Person,
    Animal,
    Plant
}

In my configuration, enums are bound from string values. For example, I have the following configuration:
{
  "Category": "Person"
}

The issue arises when the configuration contains an invalid enum value, like this:
{
  "Category": "InvalidEnumValue"
}

When this happens, the configuration binding fails and throws an exception before reaching the validation logic, with an error like:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to convert configuration value at 'Category' to type 'CategoryEnum'.
 ---> System.FormatException: InvalidEnumValue is not a valid value for CategoryEnum.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'InvalidEnumValue' was not found.

I’d like to catch this binding error and return a BadRequest or some detailed response to the client, identifying which specific property failed to bind. Ideally, I want to do this in a system-wide manner so that all enums in the application are covered.
I’d prefer not to use TypeConverters on every enum property, and I also don't want to change the enum properties to strings—I want to keep them as enums for cleaner usage throughout the codebase.
I plan to use FluentValidation later on to validate the enum values, but the issue is that the binding error occurs before I can even reach the validation layer.
Is there a way to globally handle these enum binding errors and provide detailed feedback on the invalid values?
Thanks for any suggestions!

BadRequest sounds weird. If your configuration is broken you want to wait until someone does a request against your API? Shouldn't you explicitly check your configuration at startup of the Server?

One thing that comes to my mind is to use IExceptionHandler (here are some guidelines how to do that).
Here's example implementation - it just checks if exception and inner exception are of appropriate type:
public class EnumExcpetionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Your check could look like this:
        var isInvalidOperationException = exception is InvalidOperationException;
        var isInnerFormatException = exception.InnerException is FormatException;

        if (isInvalidOperationException || isInnerFormatException)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync("Wrong enum value provided!");

            return ValueTask.FromResult(true);
        }
        
        return ValueTask.FromResult(false);
    }
}

Then you register it as usual:
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<EnumExcpetionHandler>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");


I think @wc203 is asking about configuration binding, not model binding. MEC does not use System.Text.JSON

@Mitch corrected

@MichałTurczyn Would it be possible to provide a better message like "Invalid Category provided. Allowed values are Person, Animal, Plant.". Right now, it seems to be more generalized.

I guess so, you would need to parse messages of the exceptions, try to get enum type, use reflection to scan for correct values and then construct the final message.
